# Writing step definition in cucumber for a feature file with multiple scenarios

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-java

How to write a step definition for a single feature file with multiple scenarios in cucumber?

Comment: Say for example I have a feature file with 3 scenarios, in this how my step definition should be?                                                   Should I have one step definition written for all the scenarios?  Or 3 step definition for 3 scenarios

Comment: One step definition is enough.

Answer (score 2):

From Cucumber.io's page on [Gherkin reference](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/):

```
Feature: Guess the word

  # The first example has two steps
  Scenario: Maker starts a game
    When the Maker starts a game
    Then the Maker waits for a Breaker to join

  # The second example has three steps
  Scenario: Breaker joins a game
    Given the Maker has started a game with the word "silky"
    When the Breaker joins the Maker's game
    And the Maker starts a game
    Then the Breaker must guess a word with 5 characters
```

In the above example, `the Maker starts a game` step will be implemented with something like

```
@When("the Maker starts a game")
public void theMakerStartsAGame(){
    // implementation
}
```

In the above example, step definition will map to (recognize) both the `When the Maker starts a game` and `And the Maker starts a game` steps.

That step can be reused as many times as needed in all of the feature files inside of the folder defined under `@CucumberOptions`.

Comment: Say for example I have a feature file with 3 scenarios, in this how my step definition should be?                                                   Should I have one step definition written for all the scenarios?  Or 3 step definition for 3 scenarios

Comment: 1 step in the gherkin scenario is related to 1 step definition. If you have already created the step definition, then no need to create it again - you could use the same step in the other scenarios. The steps are reusable.

Comment: @AshwiniArunachalam In the above example, step definition will map to (recognize) both the `When the Maker starts a game` and `And the Maker starts a game` steps. That step can be reused as many times as needed in all of the feature files inside of the folder defined under `@CucumberOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create feature file
2. Make sure you add correct paths to the features and step defs classes at @CucumberOptions in your cucumber runner class, such as:

   @CucumberOptions(
           features = "src/test/resources/features",
           glue = "src/main/java/stepDefs"
   )
3. Write your step realization in step definitions package using cucumber annotations like @Given, @When etc.

   @Given("Count {int} times")
   public void countMethod(int count) {
   }